# Most pandas-onic way of getting statistics about the length of lists (average lengh, highest length, etc.) in a pandas df column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to get statistics on the list lengths in a pandas df column, such average length, lowest, highest, standard deviation, etc.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

dfp = pd.DataFrame(
    {'trial_num': [[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], [3,4,6,7], [2,2]],
     'subject': [[11, 2, 2, 2],[2,2,7],[4]]
    }
)
dfp
```

Output:

```
    trial_num   subject
0   [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]  [11, 2, 2, 2]
1   [3, 4, 6, 7]    [2, 2, 7]
2   [2, 2]  [4]
```

So for this dataframe, I would like stats on the `trial_num` and `subject` columns.

So something like

```
trial_num
Average: 4
High: 6
Low: 2
Stdev: 2
```

What I have tried

I have tried

```
dfp.describe()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-8a598dabea30> in <module>()
----> 1 dfp.describe()

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py in _value_counts_arraylike(values, dropna)
    748         # TODO: handle uint8
    749         f = getattr(htable, "value_count_{dtype}".format(dtype=ndtype))
--> 750         keys, counts = f(values, dropna)
    751 
    752         mask = isna(values)

pandas/_libs/hashtable_func_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.value_count_object()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_func_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.value_count_object()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

The only solution I can think of is to use iterrows to calculation the mean, high, and low, then with the mean, use iterrows again to calculate the stdev

Comment: Using lists inside dataframes is *not pandonic to begin with*.

Comment: Is "pandonic" the preferred adjective? I was kinda hoping for "pandastic".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str.len` to get the list length of each row. Then you can use `.describe`:

```
s = dfp['trial_num'].str.len()
s.describe()


       trial_num
count        3.0
mean         4.0
std          2.0
min          2.0
25%          3.0
50%          4.0
75%          5.0
max          6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [series.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html#pandas-series-explode) or dataframe.explode and find statistics,

```
dfp['trial_num'].explode().describe()
```

Comment: I get a `
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'` error with this

Comment: It was introduced in 0.25.2, may be you are using the older version? You can find that by typing pd.__version__

Comment: He wants information about the `length` of the lists is what I understood, not the values in them.

Comment: @Erfan, yeah, looks like he is simply looking at the information of the arrays not the values contained in them